# BigQuery: How to load library into java code

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am a new dev in Bigquery.
I am following tutorial in https://developers.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-api-quickstart with Java code and imported library from https://developers.google.com/bigquery/client-libraries.
However, I couldn't load library into Java code such as
`import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.GetQueryResultsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.Job`
Please tell me know how to solve this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the necessary `.jar` files (separated by `:`) to your classpath, i.e.

```
javac -cp path/to/jar1:path/to/jar2 <your_class.java>

java -cp path/to/jar1:path/to/jar2 <your_class>
```

alternatively you can add the `.jar` files to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, i.e. (in unix systems)

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/some.jar:/path/to/some/other.jar
```

This can change depending on your environment (i.e. if you are running these in a webapp server)

Comment: In our sourcecode, I can import library for 'import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.*;'
But I can't import 'import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;'
Please tell me know to solve this case.
Thanks,

Comment: I have already answered, you need the libraries in your classpath or the compiler and jvm will not know where the libraries are, they cannot just guess the location. The `CLASSPATH` tells java where to look for external libraries

Comment: I see. We ready imported library in our source code, but I can't find the TableCell. you can see the image in the link below for more details: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sYCiN.png

Comment: You need to give more information, what do you mean `can't find the TableCell` and `couldn't load`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using maven this is done easily with the following 2 dependence
(you can changes the version to the latest one)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev12-1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev168-1.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven and the BigQuery Java Client? It is recommended to use the Java client. If so, you can easily set it up by configuring your pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
  <version>1.111.1</version>
</dependency>
```

More info on the BigQuery Java client: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery